# How to make rxjs non ui blocking?

Tags: rxjs

I have an array of items. Each item in that array represents a row in my html table and is automatically rendered when the array of items is changing.

I now wanted to use `rxjs` to add some items to that table when I click a button, so I did the following:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.$.button, 'click')
    .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.range(0, 10000))
    .subscribe((x) => {
        this.push('items', {id: '' + x, description: '' + x});
    });
```

But this is freezing the ui until every element is pushed into the array.
How can I implement it so that the ui is not freezing and still responses to user inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `range` to synchronously emit the entire range of values, you can specify a [scheduler](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/typedef/index.html#static-typedef-Rx.Scheduler).

For example:

```js
Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent(this.$.button, 'click')
    .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.range(0, 10000, Rx.Scheduler.asap))
    .subscribe((x) => {
        this.push('items', {id: '' + x, description: '' + x});
    });
```